# how to use the trackpad to scroll in nano using iterm2, the way it works in terminal.app?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2, iterm

I am used to editing in nano, and with terminal.app it's easy to quickly move up and down the file using the scroll gesture. I am trying out iTerm2, but now the scroll gesture just makes iTerm scroll upward in history, the nano work area scrolling off the bottom. in Terminal, scrolling in nano simulates moving the cursor up and down, and results in a nice ability to move through the file. How can I get iTerm2 to do this also?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It's a configurable preference (like xterm's [alternateScroll](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:alternateScroll) resource).  In iTerm2, that's in the *Advanced* tab:
[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: Works also to scroll inside a screen after pressing CTRL+A ESC

Comment: I had this set up on my previous MacBook and couldn't for the life of me figure out how to do it on my new one... Thank you sir!

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved some poor soul today (me) 

Comment: Turns out I already have this set, but it isn't working

Comment: Oh, I was in a remote screen session, so I think I ran in to https://superuser.com/a/990887/175529